# Will work done be zero when Tesla car goes uphill and comes back downhill?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, friction

If we are going uphill using Tesla car, it uses energy from the battery however when we come downhill it charges the battery, I am not sure if the charge produced while driving downhill will be equal to the charge used when going uphill but if hypothetically we consider it to be equal, will still be work done zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, because their are dissipative non-conservative forces acting on a Tesla such as air resistance, resistance from friction from the road and various kinds of internal mechanical sources of friction; there will be a non-zero net work on the car for the up and down hill round trip. Even the process of charging a battery is not one hundred percent efficient so that some energy will be lost as heat during both discharge and recharge. So, a repetitive cycle of going uphill and down hill will eventually result in a dead battery; a process that would take more time in cooler weather and less time in warmer temperatures due to the temperature dependence of battery efficiency.

However, if one considers the influence of gravity alone, then it is true that the force of gravity does not net work on the Tesla because the gravitational force is conservative, and any motion under its influence is work free for a closed path. Unfortunately, for the Tesla, gravity is not the only thing it is up against.

Comment: You can keep the battery charged forever if you load up a few heavy bags of dirt at the top and dump them at the bottom, though! Well, forever until you run out of dirt.

Answer (score 0):

When answering these questions you always have to be careful to ask "work done by what"?

It is always, always true that $W_{total}  = \Delta K$. If the Tesla is going the same speed at the start and at the end the total work done on it must be zero. This follows straight from Newton's 2nd Law.

But $W_{total}$ is made up of many parts, and when we talk about "how much work is done" we don't always mean $W_{total}$. Probably what you mean is something more like "how much battery charge am I left with?"

In this case the total work on the car is going to be
$$W_{total} = W_{engine} + W_{\text{friction, drag}}+W_{\text{charging battery}} + W_{gravity}$$

In the ideal case the change in the energy stored in the battery after the whole process would be
$$\Delta E_{batt.} = -W_{engine} - W_{\text{charging battery}}$$
except in the real car the engine and battery aren't perfectly efficient so

$$\Delta E_{battery} = -W_{engine} - W_{\text{charging}} -W_{\text{inefficiency}}$$

So in this situation, because $\Delta K = 0$ the change in energy in the battery must be

$$\Delta E_{\text{batt.}} = W_{\text{drag and friction}} + W_{\text{gravity}} - W_{\text{inefficiency}}$$

The work done by gravity is always $-mg(h_f-h_i)$ so if the Tesla starts and ends at the same height $W_{\text{gravity}} = 0$. The work done by friction and drag are always negative because they are caused by forces that act opposite the direction of motion. I've defined $W_{\text{inefficiency}}$ to be positive, so all told

$$\Delta E_{\text{batt.}} = W_{\text{drag and friction}}  - W_{\text{inefficiency}} < 0$$

So even though the total work done on the car is zero, the energy left in the battery will always be less than you started with.